# How to return value to mydatepicker from angular 4 directive

Tags: angular

am using mydatepicker in my application , on change event am getting value in directive but how to return result  value to date picker

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, Renderer, HostListener, EventEmitter, Output } from '@angular/core';
import { IMyDpOptions } from 'mydatepicker';

    @Directive({
        selector: '[DateNumberFormat]'
    })
    export class DateNumberFormat {
        @Output() ngModelChange = new EventEmitter();
        private el: any;

        constructor(
            public elementRef: ElementRef) {
            this.elementRef.nativeElement.maxLength = 8;
            this.el = this.elementRef.nativeElement;
        }

        @HostListener("change", ["$event.target.value"])


        onblur(value) {

             this.el.value = value;
            var dateObj = new Date();

            var month = dateObj.getUTCMonth() + 1; //months from 1-12
            var day = dateObj.getUTCDate();
            var year = dateObj.getUTCFullYear();

            var newdate = year + "/" + month + "/" + value;

            this.elementRef.nativeElement.value = newdate;

            //i want to return this new date to datepicker
            alert(newdate);

            return this.ngModelChange.emit(newdate);

        }
```

html

```
 <my-date-picker DateNumberFormat="true" name="mydate" id="mydate"  [options]="myDatePickerOptions" class="col-sm-8" maxlength="8"
                                        [(ngModel)]="model" required></my-date-picker>
```

value setting in element ref value but not binding to datepicker

mydatepicker reference 
https://github.com/kekeh/mydatepicker

Comment: not working , how can we return to model from directive

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the same issue, your html template code is fine. Sometime if your dateformat is not compaitabel with mydatepicker  then date will not bind to html. 
This solution will work for you.

```
import { IMyDpOptions } from 'mydatepicker';

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  public myDatePickerOptions: IMyDpOptions = {
    // other options...
    dateFormat: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
    disableWeekends : true,
};
private model: Object = {};   // this is your date model in html
constructor(){}

  ngOnInit(){
  //this.date = new Date();
  // here you also can bind date from database side also.
  this.model = {jsdate: new Date('2018-08-21')}
  }

}
```